# How to Execute flat file source by ssis catalog

Tags: ssis, flat-file, ssis-2017, ssis-connection-manager

I have a ssis pacakage which was in designed in 2008 and i have upgraded it to 2017 having flat file source.

I want to execute via ssis catalog (SSMS).

How to add file name in ssis catalog?

Comment: This is two question, File Name should be put in SSIS package, Can i know what are you mean add file name in SSIS catalog?

Comment: I have 1 package having flat file connection, given file location in package and run it via visual studio but now i want to execute this package from SSMS with the help of SSIS Catalog from different system, here how can i add my file location
 -Error: Cannot open the datafile. this error is showing while execute from ssis catalog.

Comment: if you are using flat file connection manager, you shouldn't hard code it in it, you should have package parameter and use parameter inside flat file connection manager connection expression, and when you deploy to ssis catalog, u can config this parameter at Config tab. hopefully this help you

Comment: After using project parameter it is working as expected.
Thank you for your great help.